# Getting data from two tables if they match.

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to get information from two tables in the database:
**misc.users** and **misc.course**

The misc.users table contains every person that has ever been to the institute whereas the misc.course table only has information about people that are currently enrolled on courses.

How do I get it to show only the users from the misc.users table IF there is an entry for them in the misc.course table.

The misc.users table schema is:

```
userId
userFName
userLName
userAge
userDateOfBirth
userAllergies
userNotes
```

and the misc.course schema is

```
userId
courseId
courseName
courseStart
courseEnd
courseSemGrade
courseEndGrade
```

Where **userId** is the same in both tables.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT u.* FROM course c JOIN users u ON c.userId = u.userId
```

see a working example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f98e5/1

Comment: A JOIN will return duplicate values for every instance of userId in course.

Comment: Can you explain what the random 'c' and 'u' in that query does?

Comment: I'm assuming that userId is a PK, so it should not retur duplicates. @MarkP google "sql table aliases"

Comment: If a userid has 5 courses, your query returns all of them. See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8db31/1). @MarkP. the c and u are alias. Just abreviations to make it easier to identify the tables.

Comment: @FilipeSilva assuming that one course can have **only** one time an user, if he queries "give me the ID for the users in the course with id = X" there won't be duplicates using join. Anyway in your example you are right, and adding a "distinct" will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users u
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM course c
              WHERE c.userId = u.userId)
```

This returns only the users who have at least one record in course table

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(mu.*) FROM misc.users mu 
INNER JOIN misc.course mc ON mu.userId = mc.userId
```